# singleton in ios with user defaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I am working on a mobile app that connects to my web server with a login system. I have created the user object that, after the first login, should save its token for the next app restart. I also need this user object to be a singleton so that I can access the same instance  from everywhere in my app. This is what I came up with so far:

```
+(id)sharedManager {
    static SECTUser *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}

-(id)init{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        NSString *savedToken = [ defaults objectForKey: @"token" ];
        NSString *savedName = [ defaults objectForKey: @"name" ];

        if(savedToken && savedName){
            _token = savedToken;
            _name = savedName;
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

the sharedManager is used to create the singleton, and the init should only load the values **the first time** and **on the first instantiation**.

Is this the correct way to achieve the wanted behavior? Is there any way I can check if this works properly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a break in code over here. One can directly call init method by below way.

```
SECTUser *userInfo = [[SECTUser alloc] init];
```

You should not allow this method to run outside the class. To achieve it, give proper attribute to init method by below way.

```
- (id)init __attribute__((unavailable("init is unavailable")));
```

Please refer more over [here](http://schmij.wordpress.com/2013/09/19/disable-a-method-in-objective-c/).

Comment: thank you. then how do I use the class from anywhere in my code, if I cannot init it?

Comment: You can use the class by getting object using sharedManager method. It just blocks init method. So, no one create the instance of your class outside.

Comment: thank you very much. i know it is outside the scope but, can you provide an example? marking your answer as correct by the way :)

Comment: Refer the link which I have provided in the answer. You just need to do the declaration of init method in .h file as the way shown in the answer. Rest all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
+(id)sharedManager {
    static SECTUser *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        sharedMyManager.savedToken = [ defaults objectForKey: @"token" ];
        sharedMyManager.savedName = [ defaults objectForKey: @"name" ];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}
```

btw you better store your tokens in keychain